# How to use web-ext-types to avoid error TS2304

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to build a web extension with Angular 6, so i found web-ext-types to declare the types for Web Extension API.

So just trying to make a new angular project, updating tsconfig.json to include `node_modules/web-ext-types` seems to do the job as i can see `browser` as recognized type in Visual Studio Code. So far so good.

Now i want to build my project by runnin `ng build --aot` and i've got following error: `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'browser'`.

What am I doing wrong?

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "node_modules/web-ext-types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "myLibrary": [
        "projects/my-library"
      ],
      "myLibrary/*": [
        "projects/my-library/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

also from `angular.json` :

```
"tsConfig": "projects/extension/tsconfig.app.json",
```

Created a github repo to show full code reproducing my issue: https://github.com/benk79/angular-web-ext-base

Comment: How do you include it? Can you paste your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Just editet @DanielHabenicht

Comment: The `tsconfig.json` looks ok, the problem must be elsewhere. I recommend using `"target": "es2017"` though since all browsers that support web extensions should support that. One scenario that would cause your problem is when `tsconfig.app.json` is extending a different config (it should extend the `tsconfig.json` you showed above).

Comment: Also, check the `tsConfig` setting in `angular.json`. It should point to `src/tsconfig.app.json` which should extend `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Thanks @Cito, checked your ideas with no success, and edited question to add that elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is this setting in `tsconfig.app.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "types": []
},
```

This tells the Angular CLI to run the TypeScript compiler with no type packages, overriding the `typeRoots` setting in `tsconfig.json`. This also explains why your IDE knows the `browser` namespace, but the Angular CLI does not, since the IDE only uses the `tsconfig.json` configuration, not the one in `tsconfig.app.json` which is specific to the Angular CLI. Just remove the `types` setting in `tsconfig.app.json` and the problem should be solved.